# PostgreSql copy structure of database without data

Tags: php, postgresql

I would like to create a copy of the structure only of an existing database without it data to a new database (same server).

I am using PHP 5.2.14

I tried:

```
CREATE DATABASE base3 WITH TEMPLATE base2 OWNER postgres;
```

And got this error:

```
ERROR:  source database "base2" is being accessed by other users
********** Error **********
ERROR: source database "base2" is being accessed by other users SQL state: 55006
```

I tried adding this code:

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.procpid)
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = 'base2' AND procpid <> pg_backend_pid();
```

and got this error:

```
ERROR:  function pg_terminate_backend(integer) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.procpid) FROM p...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
********** Error **********
ERROR: function pg_terminate_backend(integer) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 8
```

Answer (score 2):

In PostgreSQL 9.2 and above you should use `pg_terminate_backend` with integer argument and use `pid` field. Example bellow:

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid) 
FROM pg_stat_activity 
WHERE datname = 'base2' AND pid <> pg_backend_pid();
```

[Server Signaling Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-admin.html):

> pg_cancel_backend and pg_terminate_backend send signals (SIGINT or SIGTERM respectively) to backend processes identified by process ID. The process ID of an active backend can be found from the pid column of the pg_stat_activity view, or by listing the postgres processes on the server (using ps on Unix or the Task Manager on Windows). The role of an active backend can be found from the usename column of the pg_stat_activity view.

Comment: When I use "pid" it says column does not exist. When use: select * it confirms procpid is valid.

Comment: I think the pg_terminate_backend function is only available for PGSql v9.0 and later. I closed down my pgAdminIII. Reopened it and started the original query from the from a different database. Ran through, just copied all the data. Is there a way to "easily" Trunc every table?

Comment: No, the column name has changed (somewhere between 8.4 and 9.3) `process_pid` comes to mind...

Comment: @user3109003 `pg_stat_activity` is available from version 8.4

Comment: I am upgrading to 9.4 this weekend! Yay! Going to be nice to be current on this client! Thanks again for the input!

Answer (score 1):

`pg_stat_activity` was made available in version 8.4 and ownward.

Older version user can use these functions
[image]

as listed on documentation page

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-admin.html